# QGIS - Export layer with one polygon subdivided as multiple rows to CSV

Tags: qgis, polygon, geojson, csv, snowflake

I have a GeoJSON file with quite precise boundaries of world's countries. I had to simplify it because Snowflake, where I want to keep the data, has 16MB limit and Canadian polygon is always too large.

I used export feature to change the precision to 7, at least the GeoJSON file is now ~40MB instead of ~160MB. The geography for Canada still fails. I've tried decreasing the precision even more or simplyfing the polygon but then it results in broken geometries that even `Fix Geometries` tool can't handle.

The only other idea is to split the polygon into multiple ones. I manged to do that using `Subdivide` tool

[image]

but I don't know how to export it to CSV now and have multiple rows for Canada? However I export it, I only get 258 rows, rather than 257 + let's say 20 for Canada. Is it even possible?

Comment: Subdividing won't reduce the total number of vertices (nor the total size). You have competing goals (detailed boundary but small storage), so you first need to decide if you want to 1) reduce the size (i.e. simplify the geometries and remove the thousands of small islands, eventually change file format for a more compressed one than JSON) or 2) increase storage space (i.e. $, or change storage type or vendor) or 3) split the world in X files (i.e and deal with it when consuming the data)

Comment: I already reduced the size of the file overall by saving it with lower precision detail. It's only one polygon that is still a problem so I tried to subdividing it. 

I can't increase the storage. Snowflake doesn't allow more than 16MB of data in one cell, hence I need to work around it. Splitting the file also won't help as it's not the file's size overall, it's the complexity of that one polygon

Comment: `Multipart to singleparts` almost works but it takes each tiny polygon and separates it, not the subdivisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was possible but I forgot one crucial step.

1. Toggle Editing

[image]

2. Enable **Advanced Digitizing Toolbar**

[image]

3. Click **Split Features** tool

[image]

4. Draw a line that would split the polygon

[image]

5. Click **Toggle Editing** again to come out of edit mode and **save** the changed. (this is the step I was missing)
6. Export file. In the **Attribute Table**, you will see multiple rows for the same attribute data with different polygons.

I was doing it to split a high-precision country GeoJSON, and Canada had way too many vertices. This has allowed me to split the multipolygon into different rows of data to avoid 16MB data limit in Snowflake.

[image]